# Mysql MATCH AGAINST options: exact phrase along with extra word

Tags: mysql, django, full-text-search, match, match-against

I am trying to enhance a third part (awesome) django framework named [django-watson](https://github.com/etianen/django-watson) and I currently need to make my way through a so far unknown mysql option, the **MATCH (...) AGAINST (...)**.

So, I already know how to retrieve an exact phrase, which is doing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM patient_db 
WHERE MATCH ( Name, id_number ) 
AGAINST ('"exact phrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

An I also know how to retrieve results that contain words from a list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM patient_db 
WHERE MATCH ( Name, id_number ) 
AGAINST ('+keyword1 +keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But I need a third option, which is mixing the two above quoted. I'd like to do something like the google search: **"exact phrase" +keyword1 +keyword2**.

_*PS: when I search for **"exact phrase" -keyword1** it works exactly as desired _*

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM patient_db 
  WHERE MATCH ( Name, id_number ) 
        AGAINST ('+keyword1 +keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  OR    MATCH ( Name, id_number ) 
        AGAINST ('"exact phrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```